# Two way Sync between SharePoint online and SharePoint 2019 document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-on-prem, sync

We have 2 SharePoint environments; SharePoint online and SharePoint on-prem 2019. Each environment contain 40 libraries. and we want to sync the 2 environments, so if a files got added,edited or deleted from on-prem it should get sync in the online and the other way (from on-line to onprem). we can do this in scheduled basis.

So is there any available power shell scripts or c# code which we can use to accomplish this task?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way currently, You could use  third-party tools which have module/product SharePoint Backup and Replication for OnPrem and O365.